# Better understanding about battery session from Google Play Console Vitals

Tags: android, google-play-services, alarmmanager, wakeup, google-play-console

I would like to get a better understanding about battery session from Google Play Console Vitals monitoring dashboard.

In the new Google Play Console Vitals, the excessive wakeups are monitored. Here is the explanation given by Google :

> Percentage of battery sessions during which more than 10 wakeups
>   occurred per hour. A battery session is the period between two full
>   charges of a device. Data is collected only when the device is
>   off-charger.

What is considered as a faulty session?

If for one hour I get 14 wake ups and 0 for the next 5 hours, will the battery session be considered as faulty?

Is the period that the device is in doze mode included in the battery session?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, it is only one factor to consider in the battery session. According to this blog titled : [Android vitals: Increase engagement and installs through improved app performance](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/07/android-vitals-increase-engagement-and.html), you have to consider **Stability**, **Render Time** and **Battery Usage** (under battery usage you have to check stuck wake locks and excessive wakeups).

As previously stated, number of wake ups is considered but also the data behind those wake ups should acknowledged.

Here is a list for reference that could help:

- [Best Practices](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/android-vitals.html)
- [Stuck Partial Wake Locks](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/wakelock.html)
- [Excessive Wakeups](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/wakeup.html)

Hope this helps.